# 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found after updating GoogleMaps using pod update

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm working on an old iOS project in Objective-C that had Google Maps with version `6.2.1`. The app was working correctly.

But after using `pod update` I can't build my project. In the line `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` I'm getting the error *`'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found`*. The current Google Maps version of my project is `8.2.0`.

Here's my **Podfile**:

```
#platform :ios, '13.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '14.0'

target '<project name>' do
  use_frameworks!
  project '<project name>.xcodeproj'
  
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod "MWPhotoBrowser"
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  
end
```

I cleaned the build folder, cleaned the pod cache, installed them again, and restarted Xcode, but none worked. What am I missing here? What should I do to run my project?

Comment: Migrate to the SPM version of the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

to

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 6.2.1'
```

and then run `pod install`

everything will be fine

Comment: I'm having the same problem with MWPhotoBrowser. Can you please check this question and answer? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77272011/8192914