# 'MWCommon.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, mwphotobrowser

I am working on an old project written in Objective-C and its minimum deployment version is iOS 13.0. Recently I've updated the libraries using pod and now the project is showing the error `'MWCommon.h' file not found` in the line `#import "MWCommon.h"`
Here's my pod-file:

```
#platform :ios, '13.0'

target '<project-name>' do
  use_frameworks!
  project '<project-name>.xcodeproj'
  
  pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 6.2.1'
  pod 'SDWebImage'
  pod "MWPhotoBrowser"
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  
end
```

I've also executed the following commands and cleaned the build folder to solve this issue but it didn't work.

```
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
pod install
```

Also, as you can see in the following screenshot, `MWCommon.h` exists in *app -> pods -> MWPhotoBrowser*.

[image: Screenshot of folder tree of pod]

What can I do to make the project run again?

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to replace this:

```
#import "MWCommon.h"
```

with this:

```
#import <MWPhotoBrowser/MWCommon.h>
```

You may need to apply similar changes to any other Pods. They're part of modules, so you want to use the `<...>` syntax and `<module/file.h>`. You may also be able to use the following syntax in some case if it's convenient:

```
@import MWPhotoBrowser;
```

Comment: I followed these steps but it didn't work. What I found out later that the problem exist for every libraries except for google maps. This old project was running fine. But after updating Mac to Sonoma, Xcode to its latest version, updating CocoaPod and using ```pod update``` this problem happened. Can you please give me an idea where this problem could be? Should I change anything in the Pods.xcodeproj?

Comment: You definitely should not change Pods.xcodedproj. The pod you reference has instructions that call for `#import "MWPhotoBrowser.h"`. Beyond that, I'd probably have to look at the project itself to tell you what to do (which is unfortunately not well suited to SO). I would recommend starting from scratch in a blank project, and just add this one pod, and see if it works there, and then find what is different between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by modifying the project settings.

In the **target -> build settings** of *.xcodeproj* file of the project, I made the following changes:

- add `$(inherited)` in framework search paths
- add `$(inherited)` in header search paths
- add `${PODS_ROOT}` and `${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders` in user header search paths

In the build settings of `Pods.xcodeproj` I had to set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No".